# Select the count of records by id in the last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, I have a table in a MySQL database with the following rows and I want to be able to create a leader board based on how many views each user got on any of his monsters in the past week. The type is a tier going from 1 to 8 and has to be included in the query (the higher the `type` the higher the tier. Each row stores a single view.

> ViewId - Id of view, primary key
>
> MonsterId - Id of monster
>
> Username - Owner's name
>
> Time - PHP time() recorded

This is probably going to involve the count() thingy but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Can you show some example data?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887345/count-on-condition-in-same-column) how to add example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) :

```
select Username , COUNT(ViewId)
   from TABLENAME
   where  DATE(Time) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
   group by Username;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by Username' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select username, count(viewid)
from your_table
where `time` >= now() - interval 7 day
group by username
```